Understanding the Relationship Between Bellman Equation and Optimal Stopping Conditions in Sequential Decision Making
I'm interested in exploring the connection between the Bellman equation, commonly used in dynamic programming, and the backward induction equation associated with optimal stopping conditions, particularly in sequential decision-making processes.
In the Bellman equation framework, we often express the value function $V(s)$ as:
$$
V(s) = \max_a \left\{ Y(s, a) + \beta(s) \cdot V(T(s,a)) \right\}
$$
where $T(s,a)$ denotes the transition to the next state, and $\beta(s)$ represents discount factors ensuring convergence. Importantly, for all possible paths $S = (s_1, \ldots)$ dictated by policies, we require $\sum_{s \in S} \beta(T(s, a)) < \infty$. This condition ensures convergence under various settings, such as when all $\beta(s)$ are bounded between $0$ and $1$, or in finite horizon scenarios where $\beta(t) = 1$ for $t \leq T$ and $\beta(t) = 0$ for $t > T$.
Contrastingly, optimal stopping problems pose a different formulation encapsulated by the backward induction equation:
$$
V^{(N)}(i) = \max \left( Y(i), E[V^{(N)}(i+1) | \mathcal{F}_i] \right)
$$
Here, $\mathcal{F}_i$ represents a filtration up to time $i$, and $Y(i) = y(X_1, \ldots, X_i)$ may depend on all past observations. The essence lies in the expectation term $E[V^{(N)}(i+1) | \mathcal{F}_i]$, which suggests that the optimal decision is to halt if the immediate reward surpasses the expected value of continuing following the optimal policy. Notably, this looks just like the Bellman equation, but with the added expectation.
I'm puzzled by the absence of such an expectation in the Bellman equation. Given the presented formulations, I wonder how one could reconcile the two and whether Bellman equation variants exist that I'm unaware of.
Example
To illustrate a concrete example where the optimal stopping problem needs this expectation, consider the following scenario:
Suppose we have a sequence of length $N$, where each object in the sequence carries a value $Y(i) = X_i \sim F_i$. If you reach $N$, then you must stop.
The elegant solution to this optimal stopping problem involves defining $A(i) = E[V^{(N)}(i+1) | \mathcal{F}_i]$. Since $Y(i)$ solely depends on the immediate $X_i$, we can drop the filtration.
This simplification leads to:
$$
A(i) = E[\max\{Y(i), A(i+1)\}]\\
= \int_{-\infty}^{A(i+1)} A(i+1) dF_i + \int_{A(i+1)}^{\infty} y dF_i
$$
For instance, if $F_i = U[0,1]$, this equation reduces to $A(i) = \frac{{A(i+1)}^2 + 1}{2}$.
However, I struggle to see how the Bellman equation would naturally yield such a solution, unless there exist Bellman equation variants tailored to optimal stopping scenarios. I'm keen to receive insights into this matter.
